# When Trying to Sort an NSMutableArray using NSSortDescriptor, I get Unrecognized Selector

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to do something that seems basic, but I can't it get working.

I'm keeping track of an `NSMutableArray` of like objects. The objects have an `NSNumber` @`property` called "priority", which I am initializing like so:

```
[self setPriority:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:2]];
```

However, when I try to sort:

```
NSSortDescriptor * frequencyDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"priority" ascending:YES];
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frequencyDescriptor, nil];
NSArray * sortedArray = [tasks sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]; //This line throws the exception
```

I get this error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2c7
```

There are other questions and answers on this topic, but I get exactly the same error in every case where I try to use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort on an `NSNumber` property, and the sort does not occur.

Here is the Task class Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Task : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property NSString *name;
@property NSNumber *priority;
@property NSString *note;
@property NSString *taskID;

@end
```

### Here are the contents of NSNumber in the tasks array just before the crash:

```
2013-01-03 13:55:50.056 MyApp[9682:303] <Task: 0x10192c160>, 10
2013-01-03 13:55:50.057 MyApp[9682:303] <Task: 0x10192bc60>, 2
2013-01-03 13:55:50.057 MyApp[9682:303] <Task: 0x10190fda0>, 3
2013-01-03 13:55:50.057 MyApp[9682:303] <Task: 0x10192c6f0>, 2
2013-01-03 13:55:50.058 MyApp[9682:303] <Task: 0x10192c870>, 6
2013-01-03 13:55:50.058 MyApp[9682:303] <Task: 0x10192d1d0>, 2
2013-01-03 13:55:50.058 MyApp[9682:303] <Task: 0x10192d330>, 2
2013-01-03 13:55:50.058 MyApp[9682:303] <Task: 0x10192c530>, 5
```

All I'm looking for is to have my array of objects sorted in descending order based on the `NSNumber` property named "priority".

Why am I getting this error? I know it's probably something very obvious, but I've been stuck on this for a good 15 hours. Any help would be great.

Comment: What line exactly throws the exception?

Comment: Hi Carl. It's this line: NSArray * sortedArray = [tasks sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

Comment: Add your task class declaration to the question please.

Comment: Would you post the stack trace?

Comment: @isosigma - The class declaration looks fine, I would advise adding an Exception Breakpoint in Xcode, to better track where and why the error is being raised.

Comment: @noa Yes, I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the entries in `tasks` have priority values which are a mix of different types of objects, that at least one of them is an array, and at least one is an NSNumber. Then compare tries to compare the two, and sends the `-length` message to the number, which can't handle it.

Studying the stack trace would help confirm whether this is correct, and should also give you an idea of why the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Thanks. I posted the runtime array contents of tasks above. It looks to be filled with only Task objects. I'm populating the array at launch via NSKeyedUnarchiver like this: tasks = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fullDataFilePathWithFileName];

Comment: Alright. Have you printed out what their `priority` values are?

Comment: Added above. I noticed something when stepping through - the sortedArray is listed as having an invalid pointer. Could this be the cause? If so, I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: I gave up on the NSNumber property and just started using NSString and sorting using NSSortDescriptor * frequencyDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"priority" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]; - I don't know what's up with NSNumber, but at least I got this working.